# proof the exists of point for integral formula

Tags: integration, inequality, definite-integrals

the question goes like that:

given that $f(x)$ is integrable in $[a,b]$ , and $\left | \int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx \right | > 2$, show that for all $t \in [0,1]$, exists $s \in [a,b]$ so that:
$\left | \int_{t}^{s}f(x)dx \right | = 1$.

what I've done so far is that:
I've shown that:
$$2< \left | \int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx \right | \leq \int_{0}^{1}\left | f(x) \right |dx$$
and I can that assume that in $[a,b]$ the following inequality is true: $$2x < \left | F(x) \right |$$.
but I don't know how to procced from here, I have strong feeling that somehow I need to use the Mean Value Theorem, but I dont see how.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rough idea. $\int_0^1 f(x) dx = \int_0^t f(x) dx + \int_t^1 f(x) dx$ for all $t$. So $|\int_t^0 f(x) dx|+|\int_t^1 f(x) dx| = |\int_0^1 f(x) dx| > 2$. One of the terms on the left hand side must be greater than 1. (Why?)

Suppose it is the term $|\int_t^1 f(x) dx| > 1$. Define $F(s) = \int_t^s f(x) dx$ and $G(s) = |F(s)|$. Show that $G$ is continuous and use the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: thx, I'm trying it now